# Retrieving Template Name in Storage Extension

Tags: 2013-sp1, storage-extensions

I am working with Storage Extension in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 for Dynamic Component Presentation. Is there a way to retrieve Template Name in the `create` method while publishing a component as a Dynamic Component Presentation.

I can see that there is a way to get Template ID - `itemToCreate.getTemplateId();` but could not find a way to get Name of the template.

I tried exploring the `ComponentPresentationFactory` class as well but could not find a method to retrieve the Template Name.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
.getTemplateKey().getName()
```

on either the ComponentPresentation or ComponentPresentationKey object?

Comment: No There is no such method